# Retrieve Embedded Keys with ArduinoJSON Parser

Tags: json, parsing, arduino

I'm using this JSON parser, https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson. With the example below, I can retrieve the keys and values just fine. I'm having trouble figuring out how I would get the embedded Keys in the second example.

Example 1:
    #include

```
const char* sensor;
long time;
double latitude;
double longitude;

void setup()  { 

    Serial.begin(115200);
    char json[] = "{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";

    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

    sensor      = root["sensor"];
    time        = root["time"];
    latitude    = root["data"][0];
    longitude   = root["data"][1];

    for (JsonObject::iterator it=root.begin(); it!=root.end(); ++it)
    {
       Serial.println(it->key);
    }

} 

void loop()  { 
    // do absolutely nothing
}
```

Example 1 Output:

```
sensor
time
data
```

How would I get the keys from JSON like this?

Example 2:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup()  { 

    Serial.begin(115200);
    char json[] = "{\"Devices\":[{\"Name\":\"something\",\"ModelNumber\":\"1234\"}]}";

    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

    for (JsonObject::iterator it=root.begin(); it!=root.end(); ++it)
    {
       Serial.println(it->key);
    }

} 

void loop()  { 
    // do absolutely nothing
}
```

Example 2 Output:

```
Devices
```

EDIT:

Trying the suggested test:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup()  { 

    Serial.begin(115200);
    char json[] = "{\"Devices\":[{\"Name\":\"something\",\"ModelNumber\":\"1234\"}],\"AnotherKey\":\"itsValue\"}";

    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

    for (JsonObject::iterator it=root.begin(); it!=root.end(); ++it)
    {
       Serial.println(it->key);
    }

} 

void loop()  { 
    // do absolutely nothing
}
```

Output:

```
Devices
AnotherKey
```

Comment: Does the interator really go through the keys of the array?

Comment: TIP: Try to add another key + value, to the main / root JSON object.

Comment: @Verhagen, I tested what you suggested and it goes through the array of the un-nested keys.

Comment: Ok, it is what I expected. It seems to go just through the keys, of the outer (root) object, not through the inner array. So when there will always be an array, of devices, you need to go seperatly through the array of devices.

Comment: __TIP__ Is there something like JsonArray ?

Comment: Which Arduino Json library are you using? https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/wiki/Migrating-code-to-the-new-API

Comment: @Verhagen, I did something that worked. Seems like there should be a better way but this will work for now.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I just need to create a separate JSON Object based on the first JSON Object.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>


void setup()  { 

    Serial.begin(115200);
    char json[] = "{\"Devices\":[{\"Name\":\"something\",\"ModelNumber\":\"1234\"}],\"AnotherKey\":\"itsValue\"}";

    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
    JsonObject& root2 = root["Devices"][0];

    for (JsonObject::iterator it=root.begin(); it!=root.end(); ++it)
    {
       Serial.println(it->key);
    }

    for(JsonObject::iterator it=root2.begin(); it!=root2.end(); ++it)
    {
        Serial.println(it->key);
    }

} 

void loop()  { 
    // do absolutely nothing
}
```

Output:

```
Devices
AnotherKey
Name
ModelNumber
```

It doesn't seem super robust but it'll work for my situation.